# ESP8266 connecting to ssl secured vps, certification renewal solution

Tags: ssl, mqtt, esp8266, vps, lets-encrypt

I have a MQTT broker on my VPS, I enabled SSL using letsencrypt, right now eveything is working I am using this code on my ESP8266 devices:

```
// Load Wi-Fi library
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include<WiFiManager.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

//Enter your wifi credentials
const char* ssid = "myssid";  
const char* password =  "mypass";

// A name for our device
const char* deviceName = "devicename";

// Our mqtt server Adress and port
const char* mqttServer = "mywebsite";
const int mqttPort = 8883;

// a user defined on our server with it's password for login purpose
const char* mqttUser = " mqttUser "; //User
const char* mqttPassword = " mqttPassword"; //Password

// our gpio
#define ESP8266_LED (0)

// this is ca Certificate used as SSL key
const char caCert[] PROGMEM = R"EOF(
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
caCert Here ….
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
)EOF";

/* MQTT broker cert SHA1 fingerprint, used to validate connection to right server */
const char mqttCertFingerprint[] = "fingerprint here …";
     
/* Other globals */
X509List caCertX509(caCert);        /* X.509 parsed CA Cert */
WiFiClientSecure espClient;         /* Secure client connection class, as opposed to WiFiClient */
PubSubClient mqttClient(espClient); /* MQTT Client connection */
String clientId = "ESP8266Client-"; /* MQTT client ID (will add random hex suffix during setup) */



void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // prepare GPIO0
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
 // digitalWrite(0, LOW);


  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
  Serial.print("Connecting");
/*#endif*/
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
    Serial.print(".");
/*#endif*/
  }
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
  /* When WiFi connection is complete, debug log connection info */
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected, IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  setClock();
/*#endif*/
 /* Configure secure client connection */
  espClient.setTrustAnchors(&caCertX509);         /* Load CA cert into trust store */
  espClient.allowSelfSignedCerts();               /* Enable self-signed cert support */
  espClient.setFingerprint(mqttCertFingerprint);  /* Load SHA1 mqtt cert fingerprint for connection validation */
  
  /* Optionally do none of the above and allow insecure connections.                                             
   * This will accept any certificates from the server, without validation and is not recommended.
   */
  //espClient.setInsecure();

 /* #ifdef TLS_DEBUG
  /* Call verifytls to verify connection can be done securely and validated - this is optional but was useful during debug */
  verifytls();
/*#endif
  /* Configure MQTT Broker settings */
  mqttClient.setServer(mqttServer,mqttPort);
  mqttClient.setCallback(subCallback);

    /* Add random hex client ID suffix once during each reboot */
  clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX); 

}



void loop() {
    /* Main loop. Attempt to re-connect to MQTT broker if connection drops, and service the mqttClient task. */
  if(!mqttClient.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  mqttClient.loop();
}

/*#ifdef TLS_DEBUG
/* verifytls()
 *  Test WiFiClientSecure connection using supplied cert and fingerprint
 */
bool verifytls() {
  bool success = false;
    
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
  Serial.print("Verifying TLS connection to ");
  Serial.println(mqttServer);
/*#endif*/

  success = espClient.connect(mqttServer, mqttPort);

/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
  if (success) {
    Serial.println("Connection complete, valid cert, valid fingerprint.");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed!");
  }
/*#endif*/

  return (success);
}
/*#endif*/

void reconnect() {
  /* Loop until we're reconnected */
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT broker connection...");
/*#endif*/
    /* Attempt to connect */
    if (mqttClient.connect(clientId.c_str(),mqttUser,mqttPassword)) {
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
      Serial.println("connected");
/*#endif*/
      /* Once connected, resubscribe */
      mqttClient.subscribe("inputTopic");      
    } 
    else {
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG*/
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(". Trying again in 5 seconds...");
/*#endif
      /* Wait 5 seconds between retries */
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

// Set time via NTP, as required for x.509 validation
void setClock() {
  configTime(3 * 3600, 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
  Serial.print("Waiting for NTP time sync: ");
  time_t now = time(nullptr);
  while (now < 8 * 3600 * 2) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    now = time(nullptr);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  struct tm timeinfo;
  gmtime_r(&now, &timeinfo);
  Serial.print("Current time: ");
  Serial.print(asctime(&timeinfo));
}

void subCallback(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
  static int pinStatus = LOW;
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(256);
  deserializeJson(doc, (char*)payload);  
  JsonObject root = doc.as<JsonObject>();
  
/*#ifdef SERIAL_DEBUG  */
  serializeJson(root, Serial);
  Serial.println();
/*#endif*/

  if(!root["set"].isNull()) {
    if(root["set"] == "toggle") {
      pinStatus = !pinStatus;
    } else if (root["set"] == "on") {
      pinStatus = HIGH;
    } else if (root["set"] == "off") {
      pinStatus = LOW;
    } else if (root["set"] == "3") {
      pinStatus = LOW;
      digitalWrite(0, pinStatus);
      delay(200);
      pinStatus = HIGH;
      digitalWrite(0, pinStatus);
      delay(200);
      pinStatus = LOW;
      digitalWrite(0, pinStatus);
      delay(200);
      pinStatus = HIGH;
      digitalWrite(0, pinStatus);
      delay(200);
      pinStatus = LOW;
      digitalWrite(0, pinStatus);
      delay(200);
      pinStatus = HIGH;
      digitalWrite(0, pinStatus);
      delay(200);
      pinStatus = LOW;
    } else {
      return;
    }
    digitalWrite(0, pinStatus);
    mqttClient.publish("outTopic", pinStatus == LOW ? "off" : "on");
  } else if(!root["get"].isNull()) {
    if(root["get"] == "status") {
      mqttClient.publish("outTopic", pinStatus == LOW ? "off" : "on");
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how can I manage all my devices to get new certificate when the ssl certificate renews itself?
Is this a good way of doing this, or is there better ways to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trusting the specific leaf certificate, you need to set your code to trust the root certificates.

You are using Let's Encrypt, which means all your certificates will be signed by them. If you trust their root certificate, then it doesn't matter how many times you renew your domain certificate, it will be always trusted.

Currently, Let's Encrypt uses `ISRG Root X1` root certificate. And in the future, they are planning to switch to the `ISRG Root X2` certificate.

If you trust these two certificates, it will work for you for a long time.

You can find more information about the Let's Encrypt chain and keys for the two root certificates here:

https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/

Also, you need to remove the `setFingerprint` call and `allowSelfSignedCerts` call. The client will verify the certificate is correct automatically.

Comment: So I shouldn't be using the cert files in /etc/letsencrypt/live directory, is there any examples of implementing this? since I don't now much about how ssl works, it is very confusing, I just want to find a standard way of implementing it

Comment: The `/etc/letsencrypt/live` directory should be only used by MQTT broker. I believe your code is doing it the standard way. You just need to pass the two certificates I mentioned above to the `setTrustAnchors` function. Try to put the `ISRG Root X1` or `ISRG Root X2` (preferably both) to the `caCert[]` variable and see if it works. Here is more info about how the chain of trust works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_chains_and_cross-certification

Comment: Sorry I am new, how can I get those ISRG Root X1 and X2 ? I saw this code on github: https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/blob/development/tasmota/tasmota_ca.ino I guess they are using the same method

Comment: Is this the path: https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-x2-cross-signed.pem.txt

Comment: Does it work with that one or this one? 
https://letsencrypt.org/certs/lets-encrypt-x1-cross-signed.pem.txt